# Python argparse won`t take arguments while function called

Tags: python, argparse

My script consists of 4 functions. Two of them need arguments. I'm trying to make a simple CLI using argparse with the possibility of choosing any from the 4 functions to call.

Currently, while trying to run functions which don't need arguments, everything is OK! But when trying to run the other functions where arguments are needed, I get an error.

```
usage: test.py fun3 [-h] -x X -y Y
test.py fun3: error: the following arguments are required: -x, -y
```

trying to run from terminal using:

```
python test.py fun3 -x -y
```

```
import argparse
import sys


def fun1():
    print('Foo')

def fun2():
    print('Bar')

def fun3(x,y):
    print(x + y)

def fun4(x,y):
    print(x + y)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some stuff')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_fun1 = subparsers.add_parser('fun1', help='print Foo')
parser_fun1.set_defaults(func=fun1)


parser_fun2 = subparsers.add_parser('fun2', help='print Bar')
parser_fun2.set_defaults(func=fun2)


parser_fun3 = subparsers.add_parser('fun3', help='print x + y')
parser_fun3.set_defaults(func=fun3)
parser_fun3.add_argument('-x', type=int, required=True, help='def x')
parser_fun3.add_argument('-y', type=int, required=True, help='def y')


parser_fun4 = subparsers.add_parser('fun4', help='print x + y')
parser_fun4.set_defaults(func=fun4)
parser_fun4.add_argument('-x', type=int, required=True, help='def x')
parser_fun4.add_argument('-y', type=int, required=True, help='def y')

args = parser.parse_args()


if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    sys.argv.append('--help')

options = parser.parse_args()

options.func()
```

Comment: You didn't provide arguments.  Usage expects numbers after the flags.

Comment: Thank you! After i provided arguments ive got error ` File "test.py", line 143, in <module> options.func() AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'func' `

Comment: During debugging it's a good idea to include a `print(options)` statement to get a clear idea of what the parser has done.  Using `parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')` is also a useful idea, though it appears that you are setting the `func` attribute correctly.

Comment: `print(options)` outputs list of all functions and text from help part

Comment: If it so problematic, can you show please good example of argparse script which could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Note the functions take an `args` parameter

```
>>> # parse the args and call whatever function was selected
>>> args = parser.parse_args('foo 1 -x 2'.split())
>>> args.func(args)
2.0
```

With your code, I added the `print(args)` and `dest='cmd'` as commented.

Without the required arguments, I get an error message from the parser:

```
2106:~/mypy$ python3 stack57517701.py fun3
usage: stack57517701.py fun3 [-h] -x X -y Y
stack57517701.py fun3: error: the following arguments are required: -x, -y
```

With the correct inputs, I now get the error message from calling `fun3`:

```
2106:~/mypy$ python3 stack57517701.py fun3 -x 1 -y 2
Namespace(cmd='fun3', func=<function fun3 at 0x7facba5d60d0>, x=1, y=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack57517701.py", line 43, in <module>
    args.func()
TypeError: fun3() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

You define `fun3(x,y)`, but call `args.func()`.  The `x` and `y` are missing.

I could pass `args` to your functions, or a general `kwargs`:

```
def fun1(**kwargs):
    print('Foo')

def fun3(x=0,y=0,**kwargs):
    print(x + y)
```

and call with `args.func(**vars(args))`

```
2110:~/mypy$ python3 stack57517701.py fun3 -x 1 -y 2
Namespace(cmd='fun3', func=<function fun3 at 0x7f4bb264d0d0>, x=1, y=2)
3
```

Comment: Can you please show how the end script should look like, please. This is my first practice with CLI, hope for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The `-x` and `-y` options require parameters, you need to run it like

```
python teset.py fun3 -x 10 -y 15
```

Comment: Sorry, but it gives an error `  File "test.py", line 143, in <module>
    options.func()
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'func'
`

Comment: When i`m comenting this line - funcion calling without any output

Comment: What are you expecting `options.func()` to do?

Comment: As i understand, it gives possibility to call functions direcly from command line.